# How can I split a string and get just key part with regexp?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string like `"A < -5.9 AND B >= 6 OR (C < 3)"` I have to get keys part.(A,B,C). So I thought I should split first AND and OR then I should get key part? Could you help me? I wrote just A,B,C but in my real example A can be any string. The important thing is that is value on the right side of
<,>,<=,>=

Comment: One example is not going to be sufficient to come up with the right logic. Either provide more examples, or the rules that your expressions adhere to. With the one example you have now, just extracting all one-letter tokens would suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way would be to split using a regex:

```
"A < -5.9 AND B >= 6 OR (C < 3)".split(/ AND | OR /);

// ["A < -5.9", "B >= 6", "(C < 3)"]
```

Answer (score 0):

We can try doing a regex search for all matches on the pattern:

```
\b([A-Z]+) \S+ -?\d+(?:\.\d+)?\b
```

Sample script:

```js
var regex = /\b([A-Z]+) \S+ -?\d+(?:\.\d+)?\b/g;
var input = "A < -5.9 AND B >= 6 OR (C < 3)";
var m;

do {
    m = regex.exec(input);
    if (m) {
        console.log(m[1]);
    }
} while (m);
```

Here is an explanation of the regex pattern being used:

```
\b([A-Z]+)    match and capture a key as one or more capital letters
 \S+          match space followed by a symbol and another space
-?\d+         match a number with optional negative sign
(?:\.\d+)?\b  match an optional decimal component
```

Answer (score 0):

Without regex you caniterate the string and match the character `>` or `<`. If the character matches then create a substring and then get the last character of the substring. Also note `trim()` will remove any white space from the string

```js
let str = 'A < -5.9 AND B >= 6 OR (C < 3)';
let arr = [];
for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
  if (str[i] === '<' || str[i] === '>') {
    let subStr = str.substring(0, i).trim();
    arr.push(subStr.charAt(subStr.length - 1))
  }
};
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's just a matter of capturing variable names that appear to the left of a comparison operator:

```js
const s = "A < -5.9 AND B >= 6 OR (C < 3)";

const variables = s.match(/\w+(?=\s*[<>])/g);

console.log(variables);
```